# Counting number of trees in a forest

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I was trying to answer the following question from a textbook.

> Given n nodes of a forest and their edges, describe and prove an algorithm that finds the number of trees in the forest.

Take for instance this graph:

[image: graph]

Suppose that we explore it with a DFS, starting at vertex 0, that visits the vertices in the following order: 0, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 6.

The corresponding DFS forest will look like this:

[image: this].

The above forest contains two trees and I think we can use the below algorithm to count the number of trees in a forest. [[Source of algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-trees-forest/)]

1. Apply DFS on every node.
2. Increment count by one if every connected node is visited from one source.
3. Again perform DFS traversal if some nodes yet not visited.
4. Count will give the number of trees in forest.

My question is: How can I prove that this algorithm is correct, and is there a more efficient algorithm to get the number of trees in a forest?

Comment: Your algorithm description needs to be more precise. For instance, if step 1 means what it says then why should you perform step 3 again from the same nodes? Where does the DFS start in step 3? How will you find such node? What exactly is step 2 doing? How will you check "if every connected node is visited from one source"?

Comment: in terms of efficiency, you wouldn't need to DFS from nodes that you have already seen, so in your example, you would only need to run DFS twice, not 7 times

Comment: @trincot you are right. Step 1 and 3 do the same thing. When we do DFS on the above graph starting at 0 the first node that turns black will be 1 then 5 2 4 and finally 1. And when all turns black that means we are done with that tree and we will run the DFS (the DFS in step three starts here) again for the other nodes (white).

Comment: Apart from the vague algorithm description, the code that goes with it (in the link) takes away the doubts: that is the most efficient algorithm in terms of time complexity.

Comment: @trincot so how can I rewrite the algorithm?